# Save the binary fingerprint data in the table in database

Tags: database, binary, save, fingerprint

I want to save the enrolled fingerprint from my device to database and want to retrieve it during the time of verification either in same table or in different table. I tried some of the codes here like BLOB. But didn't work. I have converted the fingerprint data to binary data using

```
NBioAPI.Type.FIR biFIR;           
m_NBioAPI.GetFIRFromHandle(hNewFIR, out biFIR);
```

after successful enrollment of users.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert it to ANSI or ISO fingerprint template formats if your fingerprint API provisions for that then save that in your BLOB field. I use BLOB or VARBINARY and it works fine

Comment: can you please tell me how to store this ISO fingerprint template in mysql database and also how to match these against other finger prints. I am using java and mysql.

Comment: It should be easy to do that if a fingerprint reader's API has a good documentation. You can identify the methods from your API for converting a fingerprint template into an iso then save the resulting ISO template into MySQL database.

When matching, convert extracted templates from fingerprint to ISO and compare against other saved ISO fingerprint templates in your MySQL database
 There should be an ISO compare function to help you with that in your API if it does support fingerprint templates conversion to ISO.